# Unable to get the PivotTables Property of the Worksheet Class

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use some VBA that another person made and it is giving me an error that I can't seem to fix.  Here's the code:

```
Sub Format_Homeward_V3()
' Format_Homeward_V3 Macro
    ChDir "J:\Templates"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "J:\Templates\Homeward_Exception_Report_Template_Final.xlsx"
    Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "J:\Templates\Homeward_Inventory_Report_Template_Final.xlsx"
    Range("A4").Select
    Sheets("Homeward_Summary").PivotTables("MyPivot").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("Detail").Select
    Range("A1").Select
```

it errors out at:

```
Sheets("Homeward_Summary").PivotTables("MyPivot").PivotCache.Refresh
```

and gives the error:

> "unable to get the pivottables property of the worksheet class"

But as far as I can tell it is looking at the right sheet and the right name of the PivotTable.  I also tried doing `.RefreshTable` instead of cache refresh but got the same error.  I don't really know why it would be giving me this error and and I don't know what else to try.  It's been working without this error for a while.

Comment: what number do you get when you `?Sheets("Homeward_Summary").PivotTables.Count` in the Immediate Window?

Comment: are you sure the pivot table name is what you think it is. if you right click on the pivot table and go to properties what does the name say? or you can `?Sheets("Homeward_Summary").PivotTables(1).Name` in the `Immediate Window` to get the name.

Comment: and why do you open the same workbook twice? and see the answer below. it may solve your issue.

Comment: weird, i explicitly renamed the pivot table MyPivot to test if that was the problem but in the Immediate Window it says it is "Microsoft Office PivotTable 10.0" so I am changing it to that in my code.  It looks like that might have solved it but I also used the answer below's code in place of mine.

Comment: bizarre - but glad you got it solved. try renaming it again?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure everything is  referenced, then there is no guesswork about which workbook or sheet you are trying to deal with (pardon the shorthand, alter as required)

```
Sub Format_Homeward_V3()
Dim wbe As Workbook
Dim wbi As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set wbe = Workbooks.Open("J:\Templates\Homeward_Exception_Report_Template_Final.xlsx")
Set wbi = Workbooks.Open("J:\Templates\Homeward_Inventory_Report_Template_Final.xlsx")
Set ws = wbi.Sheets("PIVOT")
ws.Range("A4").Select
ws.PivotTables("MyPivot").PivotCache.Refresh
```