# Runtime Error 1004: Unable to get the PivotTables property of the worksheet class. My recorded macro doesnt run?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-chart

This is driving my nut, i spent the last hour trying to find a fix to these with no success.
I have a few PivotCharts in a worksheet and i need to refresh them manually.
So i tried to record a macro doing a left click and a refresh, here is the result of the macro :

```
ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotChartTable5").PivotCache.refresh
```

ok, when i tried to run the the macro, i have the following error :

[image]

And if i get rid of the first 2 lines of the macro, select one chart and run the macro (the last line only) i have the following error :

[image]

I need help.
I tried to replace the activeSheet with the current sheet (`Sheets.("mysheet")`), doesnt help :(
One thing, if i click on the chart, i dont find the `PivotChartTable5` name anywhere, my charts are called something like `Chart 12` or whatever the number.

Thanks

Comment: What's the name of the pivot *table*?

Comment: table is called "intradays"  so nothing related to PivotchartTable ...

Comment: That's your problem then. `PivotTables("PivotChartTable5")` is referencing a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: Clearly you should modify the name of the pivot table to the one that actually exists, right?

Comment: just tried it, no success. Well, i also tried to change it to the name of the actual chart to no success neither. Just ot make it more clear, this is a pivot chart that i'm trying to update, not the pivot table.

Comment: Start by using specific worksheets and charts etc held in variables. Test that each can be found first and then combine. Avoid ActiveSheet and ActiveChart and be explicit. With explicit references you can get rid of using .Select as well.

Comment: i just did (following the answer of that page : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923305/unable-to-get-the-pivottables-property-of-the-worksheet-class) ). No success :( i have a "Method 'PivotTables' of object '_Worksheet' failed error 1004

Comment: But the property is `PivotTables`, not `PivotChart`. Work with the *table*, not the chart.

Comment: yes it's what i thought as well, but what is the property for pivotchart ?